# Differnce between rails db:create and rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently learning rails. I was wondering what is the difference between rails db:create and rake db:create and vise versa for migrate? I know they both create databases but why are there two functions that do the same thing? Is one of them best suited for a particular situation?

Answer (score 7):

No difference! You can run ***all Rake tasks*** with the  `rails` keyword in *Rails 5*.
So

`rake db:create`

will become

`rails db:create`

Answer (score 3):

All *rake* commands have been replaced with *rails* in *Ruby 5*. They achieve the same task.